# How to add new element into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to port code from blackberry to android and facing small problem:
Example: the bb code is:

```
public class MyClass{
   private MyObject[] _myObject;

   public void addElement(MyObject o){
      if (_myObject == null){
        _myObject = new MyObject[0];
      }
      Arrays.add(_myObject, o);
   }
}
```

unfortunately android does not have `Arrays.add()` which is part of `net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays`  (`static void add(Object[] array, Object object)`)

Is there any replacement for android to dynamically extend and append in to simple array so I don't change the rest of my code.

I tried to write my own utility but it does not work:

```
public class Arrays {
  public static void add(Object[] array, Object object){
    ArrayList<Object> lst = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object o : array){
      lst.add(o);
    }
    lst.add(object);
    array = lst.toArray();
  }
}
```

.. after I call

```
public void addElement(MyObject o){
      if (_myObject == null){
        _myObject = new MyObject[0];
      }
      Arrays.add(_myObject, o);
   }
```

the `_myObject` still contain 0 elements.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because the `_myObject` reference is passed by value. You'd need to use:

```
public static Object[] add(Object[] array, Object object){
  ArrayList<Object> lst = new ArrayList<Object>();
  for (Object o : array){
    lst.add(o);
  }
  lst.add(object);
  return lst.toArray();
}

...

_myObject = Arrays.add(_myObject, o);
```

However, it would be better to just use an `ArrayList<E>` to start with...

There are two important things to understand here:

**Java *always* uses pass-by-value**

The value which is passed is either a reference (a way of getting to an object, or null) or a primitive value. That means if you change the value of the *parameter*, that doesn't get seen by the caller. If you change the value of something *within the object the parameter value refers to*, that's a different matter:

```
void doSomething(Person person) {
  person.setName("New name"); // This will be visible to the caller
  person = new Person(); // This won't
}
```

**Arrays are fixed-size in Java**

You can't "add" a value to an array. Once you've created it, the size is fixed. If you want a variable-size collection (which is a very common requirement) you should use an implementation of `List<E>` such as `ArrayList<E>`.

Comment: thanks for quick answer. Please, take a look to this spec: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html   There is void add(Object[] array, Object object);  How do rim developers achieve that it works for them? I mean they just call add(object_array, new_element); and object_array extended with new element?

Comment: @kompotFX: They don't. It's entirely unclear what that badly-documented method does, but I can guarantee you that if you print out `array.length`, then call `add(array, "hello")`, then print `array.length` again, it'll have the same value. It's possible that it looks for an element in the array which has a null value, and set the value of that element to the one that was passed in. That's not the same thing as *adding* though.

Comment: it is very strange, because actually the sample of code I need to port works on blackberry.

Comment: @kompotFX: Well the code you've given at the top would *always* leave `_myObject` as a length-0 array. That's assuming RIM hasn't broken the way that Java works, of course, but I doubt that they have. If you can show a short but complete program showing RIM's code working, that would be useful.

Comment: so, you want to say that RIM developers are wrong with this: <http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html#add(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object)> ?

Comment: @kompotFX: Almost certainly, unless their "version" of Java is fundamentally different to everyone else's. Again, some sample code showing how that code "works" would be useful.

Comment: unfortunately it is a part of huge project and I am sure 100% that this application and currently this method works on blackberry device.

Comment: @kompotFX: Just because you've got something working as part of a big project doesn't mean you'd have to post the project. Just a short but complete bit of code which shows it working. Something which creates an array of length 5 (say), passes a reference to that array to the `Arrays.add` method, and then prints out the length again afterwards...

Comment: check real example here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/CS_record_video_without_using_the_camera_app_734825_11.jsp   Look for method  private String[] getEncodings()

Comment: @kompotFX: Right, that seems unambiguous. Under normal Java, there is **no way** that can work. So either their code really is broken, or their implementation of Java is completely wacky.

Comment: @kompotFX: Just looking at [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Where-is-Arrays-add/td-p/395462) it looks like it's gone in later versions of the API... so maybe they've stopped the craziness over time.

Answer (score 2):

- [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has `ArrayUtils.add(..)`
- [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has `ObjectArrays.concat(..)`.

Here's the code of `ObjectArrays.concat(object, array)`:

```
public static <T> T[] concat(@Nullable T element, T[] array) {
    T[] result = newArray(array, array.length + 1);
    result[0] = element;
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, 1, array.length);
    return result;
  }
```

The apache-commons code is a bit longer.