# How to add new element to Varargs?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have a method

```
public boolean findANDsetText  (String Description, String ... extra ) {
```

inside I want to call another method and pass it `extras` but I want to add new element (Description) to extras.

```
     object_for_text = getObject(find_arguments,extra);
```

How can I do that in java? What would the code look like?

I tired to accommodate code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687342/how-to-add-new-element-into-an-array) but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a varargs method with an additional argument from a varargs method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293989/how-to-call-a-varargs-method-with-an-additional-argument-from-a-varargs-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extra` is just a `String` array. As such:

```
List<String> extrasList = Arrays.asList(extra);
extrasList.add(description);
getObject(find_arguments, extrasList.toArray());
```

You may need to mess with the generic type of `extrasList.toArray()`.

You can be faster but more verbose:

```
String[] extraWithDescription = new String[extra.length + 1];
int i = 0;
for(; i < extra.length; ++i) {
  extraWithDescription[i] = extra[i];
}
extraWithDescription[i] = description;
getObject(find_arguments, extraWithDescription);
```

Comment: I get `Cannot invoke asList() on the array type String[]` for the first option.

Comment: Did you mean to use `Arrays.asList(extra)`? (see Radek's comment).

Comment: Now I get `Cannot invoke toArray() on the primitive type boolean` for `Arrays.asList(extra).add(Description).toArray()`

Comment: Will given an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: This will no longer work (tested with Java 8u144) since Arrays.asList() returns an fixed-size List. Suggest to use Arrays.copyOf(...).

Answer (score 13):

To expand on some of the other answers here, the array copy could be done a bit faster with

```
String[] newArr = new String[extra.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(extra, 0, newArr, 0, extra.length);
newArr[extra.length] = Description;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Arrays.copyOf(...)` :

```
String[] extra2 = Arrays.copyOf(extra, extra.length+1);
extra2[extra.length] = description;

object_for_text = getObject(find_arguments,extra2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public boolean findANDsetText(String description, String ... extra)
{
    String[] newArr = new String[extra.length + 1];
    int counter = 0;
    for(String s : extra) newArr[counter++] = s;
    newArr[counter] = description;

    // ...

    Foo object_for_text = getObject(find_arguments, newArr);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simply this way...

Treat the Var-args as below...

**Example:**

In your above example the 2nd parameter is "String... extra"

So you can use like this:

```
extra[0] = "Vivek";
extra[1] = "Hello";
```

**Or**

```
for (int i=0 ; i<extra.length ; i++)

  {

          extra[i] = value;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 11 use as parameter for a new List:

```
List<String> templateArguments = new ArrayList<(Arrays.asList(args));
templateArguments.add(throwable.getMessage());
String.format(template, templateArguments.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to list and back to array, but shorter using utility functions:

```java
// import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

var descriptionAndExtra
    = Lists.asList(description, extra).toArray(new String[extra.length + 1]));
```