# How to add arguments to varargs?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Suppose I have methods

```
void m1(Object... objs) {
   m2("added", objs);
}
```

and

```
void m2(Object... objs) {
   for (Object o : objs) {
      // do something with Object o
   }
}
```

If I call `m1("a", "b")`, I'd like `m2` to see an array of 3 Objects (Strings "added", "a" and "b"). However, instead `m2` sees just 2 objects: String "added" and an `Object[]` array, which internally contains Strings "a" and "b".

How can I get the desired behavior, that is, I simply add elements to the varargs before forwarding them to another method?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to go around this, but your suggestion of "simply add elements to the varargs before forwarding them to another method" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321784/how-to-add-new-element-to-varargs

Comment: @JNL That's not a duplicate.

Comment: Do it with the arrays directly, basically.

Comment: @RohitJain I never said it's a duplicate. I was helping the OP with a similar question. Thought it would help.

Comment: @JNL. OOPs, sorry. I thought you closed it as duplicate.

Comment: @RohitJain Thats all right, not a problem. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a method like this:

```
public static Object[] merge(Object o, Object... arr) {
    Object[] newArray = new Object[arr.length + 1];
    newArray[0] = o;
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArray, 1, arr.length);

    return newArray;
}
```

and, subsequently:

```
m2(merge("added", objs));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a `List`, add your new element, add the elements from the varagrs array, then transform the `List` back to an array.

```
void m1(Object... objs) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("added");
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(objs));
    m2(list.toArray());
}
```

With a `LinkedList` you could call `addFirst()`.

Comment: Good solution, however it breaks the order he originally specified. `list.add("added");` should come before `list.addAll(...)`

Comment: @StormeHawke Yes, thanks. Edited to depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Varargs is functionally the same as passing in an array, except that the user is not required to construct the array. As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), "the final argument may be passe as an array *or* as a sequence of arguments" (original italics). As such, if passed as a sequence of arguments, the array is constructed from the variable arguments passed in.

In your case, you want to add something to that array... so you have to create a new array:

```
void m1(Object... objs){
  Object[] newObjs = new Object[objs.length + 1];
  newObjs[0] = "added";
  System.arraycopy(objs, 0, newObjs, 1, objs.length);
  m2(newObjs);
}
```