# Forwarding variable number of parameters to function that accepts variable number of parameters via the ellipse operator

Tags: java

In short, I have a function that accepts a variable number of params and another function that also accepts a variable number of paramaters, I need to forward all the variable paramaters in the method plus some extra to the second method that accepts variable paramaters ...

```
action1(new Filter1());
action2(new Filter1(), new Filter2());

public void action1(Object ... params){
    actionGeneric(new Action1(), params);
}

public void action2(Object ... params){
    actionGeneric(new Action2(), params);    
}

public void actionGeneric(Object ... params){
    for (Object param : params){
        if (param instanceof Action1){
            // works fine
        } else if (param instanceof Action2){
            // works fine
        } else if (param instanceof Filter1){
            // never gets here
        } else if (param instanceof Filter2){
            // never gets here
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how should I be forwarding those params in action1 / action2 in order for actionGeneric to see them as Filter1 / Filter2 instances and not (I'm guessing) array type?

Comment: A solution would be to change your design. Make your `Action1` and `Action2` implement a common interface to avoid usage of `instanceof`. Similar for your `FilterX` and pass something different than `Object ... params`.

Comment: Something looks wrong - this code should reach the "never gets here" lines.  Is it possible to debug by printing out `param.getClass().getName()` inside the for loop?

Comment: `java` functions don't start with `function`. Please post real code. Or is this `javascript`?

Comment: Sorry, it's java code, working in multiple languages at the moment, so mixed some stuff in there that should not be there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add arguments to varargs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475232/how-to-add-arguments-to-varargs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `action2()` method, you call the `actionGeneric()` method with two arguments: `new Action2()` and `params` (the latter of which is an Object array). Thus, from the point of view of the `actionGeneric()` method, some arguments are of type `Action2` but not `Filter1`. The solution, I think, would be to create a new array before passing it to the `actionGeneric()` method, along the lines of...

```
Object[] newParams = new Object[params.length + 1];
newParams[0] = new Action1();
System.arraycopy(params, 0, newParams, 1, params.length);
actionGeneric(newParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

If a single array is passed to a variable-argument method, it will be treated as variable arguments.  So, create a new array like this:

```
  Object[] newArray = new Object[params.length + 1];
  newArray[0] = new Action1();
  System.arraycopy(params, 0, newArray, 1, params.length);

  actionGeneric(newArray);
```

Comment: Jae Heon Lee beat me to it.